# Como não permitir o usuário de criar HTML usando input text?

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Eu sou relativamente iniciante em programação, tenho 17 anos, 2 anos com programação mas sem experiência no mercado de trabalho e recentemente comecei a trabalhar mais ativamente com HTML.

O meu problema é com relação ao fato de que os usuários podem alterar o layout do meu site HTML usando o input. Por exemplo, se eles digitam no campo nome o código `<button>Teste</button>`, eles conseguem criar um botão com o valor "Teste". Eu gostaria que assim como no GitHub, caso eles tentem fazer isso seja mostrado por extenso o `<button>Teste</button>` e não criado um botão. Mais abaixo vou mostrar nas imagens de como está e como gostaria que fosse feito.

Já procurei por perguntas no StackOverflow Americano e Brasileiro e em outros fontes mas ainda não achei nada parecido como o que eu procuro.
Tentei reproduzir o que eu vi no código fonte dos comentários do Facebook e da Biografia do GitHub mas não deu certo.

**MEU SITE**

Entrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída (Código da Página):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**GITHUB**

Entrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída (Código da Página):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, no meu caso foi criado um div, no caso do GitHub foi criado por extenso, apenas como texto. Eu gostaria que o meu modelo ficasse igual ao GitHub, em outras palavras, que o usuário não fosse permitido de alterar o layout do site utilizando input.

Segue o meu código html:

```
<label for="name" class="txt_settings_text">Nome:</label>
<br>
<!--Essa é a caixa onde o usuário insere o nome (Entrada)-->
<?php echo '<input id="prof_txt_name" type="text" name="name" value="'.$data['userName'].'" maxlength="35">' ?>
<!--Aqui é apenas exibido o texto (Saída)-->
<span id="prof_lbl_name" class="txt_settings_text"><?php echo $data['userName']; ?></span>
```

Segue a minha query usando MySqli:

```
        SELECT
            userName,
            userSurname,
            userUsername,
            userEmail,
            userPassword,
            userCountry,
            userGender,
            userPhone,
            userCellphone,
            userBio,
            userPhoto,
            userBackground,
            userRegistertime
        FROM hanabiUser
        WHERE
            userEmail = '".$_SESSION['email']."'
```

Além das coisas que já citei, tentei:

- Botar aspas dentro do span;
- Trocar o span por outras tags como div e p.

Desde já, obrigado a todos que se oferecerem para ajudar!

Comment: Vc tem que "sanitizar" seu input, talvez isso ajude https://php.docow.com/maneira-correta-de-sanitizar-a-input-no-mysql-usando-dop.html e isso tb https://kevinsmith.io/sanitize-your-inputs

Comment: A sua resposta me ajudou de certa maneira, eu não sabia sobre isso e isso me ajudou no sentido de que agora posso fazer as minhas consultas e o meu banco mais seguro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de você proibir que o usuário entre com código `HTML` no seu `INPUT`, você pode contornar o problema usando a função [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) para escapar todo o conteúdo digitado, por exemplo:

```
$saida = htmlentities($entrada);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu o meu problema!!